# Pandas - Loop Control - Control the behavior of loop based on column value comparison

Tags: python, pandas, loops, comparison, row

Let's say I have a Pandas DataFrame as below:

```
Row | Column1 | Column2 | Column3
0 | abc | 10 | NY
1 | abc | 20 | NY
2 | abc | 15 | CA
3 | xyz | 10 | RI
4 | xyz | 30 | NV
5 | lmn | 15 | MN
```

Now, I want to do multiple operations on values of column2 and column3 but only when the value of column1 changes. That is, the loop should run through for the first three rows and activate a different code when value changes. Something like this in traditional languages:

```
prev = df[0:1]
    for row in df:
       if prev.column1 == row.column1:
          <some code>
          continue
       else:
          <some other code>
    
       prev = row
```

Currently, the python equivalent of the code above I have tried is not working for me since it says the truth value of the series is ambiguous. If I fix that by using `.any()` on the condition, then it works fine for the first change of column1 value, but then throws; bool has no attribute 'any'.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Thanks for providing input. What is your expected output?

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response David.

Comment: The expected output for me is a custom weighted average formula applied on column1 based on values of column2. i.e. something like below:

0 | abc | (((10 * (NY/7)) + (20 * 3NY) + (15 * CA))/(150)) 

I believe this final state cannot be accommodated in the existing dataframe. Hence I intend to create a new one with just two columns. column1 and custom formula. 

This is my expected output, hope it makes sense!

Comment: Thanks, based off this, can you update your question with new input data, and importantly output data, or has my solution provided you with enough information to take this away? In the code: `df['Column2'] = np.where(condition, df['Column2'] + 100, df['Column2'])` , all you need to do is replace this logic: `df['Column2'] + 100` with the logic you posted in your comment. Same for `Column3`. Kindly accept the solution if it helps you solve.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `.shift()` to compare values in columns row-wise.
2. You can use `np.where()` to change the data depending on conditions and operations.

---

First, let's create the condition with:

`condition = (df.shift()['Column1'] != df['Column1']) & df.index > 0`

1. This condition flags a row as `True` or `False` if the value in `Column1` is different than the previous row `Column1` value with `(df.shift()['Column1'] != df['Column1'])`.
2. However, this will also flag the first row, so you can add `df.index > 0` as another condition to ignore the first row.

---

Next, let's make some operations on the dataframe based on the condition:

`df['Column2'] = np.where(condition, df['Column2'] + 100, df['Column2'])`

`df['Column3'] = np.where(condition, df['Column3'] + ' (adjusted)', df['Column3'])`

3. Use `np.where()`, where the *first argument* you pass is the custom `condition` variable that you just created.
4. The *second argument* you will pass is whatever operation you want to take place if the first argument (`condition`) is `True`. For example, `df['Column2'] + 100` or `df['Column3'] + ' (adjusted)'`
5. The *third argument* you will pass is what should be returned if the `condition` is `False`. In this case, just return what the column value was originally, by putting in the column with `df['Column2']` or `df['Column3']`

---

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
condition = (df.shift()['Column1'] != df['Column1']) & df.index > 0
df['Column2'] = np.where(condition, df['Column2'] + 100, df['Column2'])
df['Column3'] = np.where(condition, df['Column3'] + ' (adjusted)', df['Column3'])
df
Out[22]: 
   Row Column1  Column2        Column3
0    0     abc       10             NY
1    1     abc       20             NY
2    2     abc       15             CA
3    3     xyz      110  RI (adjusted)
4    4     xyz       30             NV
5    5     lmn      115  MN (adjusted)
```